# Magento get all products in a certain category ordered by the 'Position' field

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am simply trying to get all products that belong to a certain `category ID` in the `Position` order they are set in the back end.

I seemed to have tried every example available to no avail.

The basic code I'm working with is as follows (external php file that loads magento manually):

```
// Load Magento
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/app/Mage.php";
umask(0);
Mage::app();
// set Store ID
$store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
// set Cat ID
$cat_id = 345;


$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setId(345);

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addCategoryFilter($cat)
    ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
    ->setOrder('name','asc')
    ->load();

foreach($products as $p) {
    var_dump($p->getName());
}
```

How might I achieve this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This was what finally worked:

```
$cat_id = 345;

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id);
$collection = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSort('position');
Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    var_dump( $product->getName() );
}
```

Comment: To continue with @WilliamIsted, this is still working in 1.9.

Answer (score 2):

```
$product_position_array = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($CategoryID)->getProductsPosition();
```

This should return an array of `$product_id = $position`.

Comment: Why the down vote?  Sure my formatting wasn't great but 3 lines to 1 and using the correct model isn't a better way to go?  I suppose I could have been more specific since the OP wanted the array in order of position but that simply requires sorting the array by value at this point.