# Magento: Keep category filter list in nav

Tags: magento, filter, attributes

I have been searching and trying various methods, but to no avail.

I have 2 categories: Red Wine and White Wine.

Each category has products with attributes that are filterable.

I want to display all the filterable options (that have active products assigned to them), as a constant nav menu. Even if i go into the category and filter it, the nav menu should stay the same.

So it the nav menu will always look like the below, regards less of category filter (which i still want to work):

```
- Red Wine
--- Shiraz (3)
--- Merlot (4)

- White Wine
--- Charonnay (2)
--- Rose (7)
```

ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `Topmenu.php` Block. Step to override:

Copy: `\app\code\core\Mage\Page\Block\Html\Topmenu.php`

Paste: `\app\code\**local**\Mage\Page\Block\Html\Topmenu.php`

You need to create same directory path into to `local` directory, then paste `Topmenu.php`

After copy, open copied file `\app\code\**local**\Mage\Page\Block\Html\Topmenu.php` and edit `protected function _getHtml` function.

To get category id: `$catId = str_replace('category-node-','',$child->getId());`

Fetch all product from this category group by certain attribute. Help links:

[Magento products by categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272818/magento-products-by-categories)

[Magento get all products in a certain category ordered by the 'Position' field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318488/magento-get-all-products-in-a-certain-category-ordered-by-the-position-field)

Hope this will help!